# Getting data from mlab without request i.e. reloading the page to show in front end

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ajax, express, mlab

So I know a lot of people has asked questions similar to mine, but I have a different problem.
What I am hoping for is to retrieve data from my database in mlab without reloading the page. For example a current game score(in my example cricket score) is added to my db in mlab, now I want this new score in my front end web page without router request i.e. wanting a user to reload the page.
Technologies I know and I am using is mongodb, mongoose, nodejs and express.

And I think angular or AJAX is going to help me but i have no idea about them.
So please explain clearly and in detail.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `mongodb` node module. Here is an example:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect('link-to-mongodb', (err, database) => {
  // ... start the server
})
```

the `'link-to-mongodb'` should come from your mLab account: 
[image]

[This](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) is a really good tutorial on using mLab with your nodeJS server, it is also where I got the above image/code from.

Comment: that was not my question. I have already connected the database and I know how to manupilate the data using request to routes, what I want is to get the data from db without sending request. @pudility

Comment: You cant. You must ask for data from the database, otherwise it won't know what data to give you.